Does enumerating an auto-generated IAsyncEnumerable release its current item before awaiting the next?
Simple example:
public abstract class Example {
    protected abstract Task<ReallyLargeItem> GetItem();
    
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<ReallyLargeItem> Producer() {
        while(true) {
            yield return await GetItem();
        }
    }

    public async Task Consumer()
    {
      await foreach(var item in Producer())
        Console.WriteLine(item == null ? "hello" : "world); // Just print something silly to signify the JIT cannot optimise this away here
    }
}

Let's say

Producer publishes a really really big item rather immediately after Consumr starts enumerating.
Then, nothing happens for the next hour, Producer does not yield any more items during that time.

Will the item become free-able (by the GC) pretty much immediately once Consumer has printed its first line and hits the second awaitable iteration of the loop?
Or would its generated enumerator hold on to a reference of the first item produced until a second item is actually yielded by Producer - meaning, for at least an hour?
I'm aware SharpLab has the answer in theory, but looking at the generated state machines, I'm unfortunately not very hopefuly I can decipher it..


Will the item become free-able (by the GC) pretty much immediately once Consumer has printed its first line and hits the second awaitable iteration of the loop?

No, it won't become eligible for garbage collection. Iterators in C# are implementing the IEnumerable<T>/IAsyncEnumerable<T> interfaces, and these interfaces require two method calls in each iteration. First you must call MoveNext/MoveNextAsync to learn if the sequence has any more elements, and then you must call the get accessor of the Current property in order to get the next available item. Getting the Current is not a mutating operation. The Current is not nullified after you get it. You are allowed to get the Current multiple times if you want, and every time you'll get the same element. From the docs:

Current returns the same object until MoveNext is called. MoveNext sets Current to the next element.

So when exactly is the Current replaced by the next value of the sequence? It is replaced when the next MoveNextAsync operation completes asynchronously. In other words it is replaced when the ValueTask<bool> completes, not when the MoveNextAsync operation is launched. This can be proved experimentally. Let's observe for example the behavior of the sequence below:
async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Produce()
{
    yield return 1;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    yield return 2;
}

This sequence produces the value 1 immediately, and the value 2 after a delay of one second. The complete experiment can be found here. It produces this output:
11:49:47.150 [1] > 1st MoveNextAsync result: True
11:49:47.170 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.174 [1] > 2nd MoveNextAsync started
11:49:47.175 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.275 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.375 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.475 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.576 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.676 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.776 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.876 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:47.977 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:48.077 [1] > Current: 1
11:49:48.177 [1] > 2nd MoveNextAsync result: True
11:49:48.177 [1] > Current: 2

We can see that while the 2nd MoveNextAsync operation is in-flight, the Current is stuck with the value 1. This means that in your case the ReallyLargeItem will not be eligible for garbage collection during the prolonged period of time (possibly hours) that the producer has nothing to produce, and so the pending MoveNextAsync operation stays inert in the non-completed state.
As a side note you might be surprised to know that the Current is not nullified when you Dispose/DisposeAsync the enumerator. See this question for details. This questionable behavior is unlikely to change, because of backward compatibility concerns.
In case you are enumerating memory-heavy objects, probably the best you can do is to store your objects in a mutable wrapper, and unlink the object from the wrapper when you have finished working with the heavy object. A handy class to use as a wrapper is the StrongBox<T>.
public async IAsyncEnumerable<StrongBox<ReallyLargeItem>> Producer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new(await GetItem());
    }
}

public async Task Consumer()
{
    await foreach (var box in Producer())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(box.Value is null ? "hello" : "world");
        box.Value = default; // Let the ReallyLargeItem be recycled.
    }
}

The alternative is to abandon the convenience of iterators, and code your enumerables by hand.

Thanks - that is surprising indeed! Even the docs you quoted sound a little ambiguous to me, i.. "Current returns the same object until MoveNext is called. MoveNext sets Current to the next element." - MoveNext is implicitly called again immediately after the first element is received. So the big question I reckon is whether Current is replaced when MoveNext is called, or when MoveNext completes - based on your answer though, sounds like the latter!

@Bogey yeah, I haven't verified it experimentally, but my guess is that the Current is replaced when the MoveNextAsync completes asynchronously (when the ValueTask<bool> completes).

@Bogey in case your app produces many IAsyncEnumerable<ReallyLargeItem> sequences, you could consider writing your own iterator-style engine with better memory-management behavior. For example your enumerables could have the behavior of allowing a single read of the Current property (after each MoveNextAsync), and then throw an exception if a second read attempt is made. Writing such an engine is not trivial, but it can be done as demonstrated by the Dasync/AsyncEnumerable package.

@Bogey if you do that though, I have no idea what will happen if your optimized enumerables become the source of a LINQ query (Select, Where etc). It's possible that doing so would de-optimize the sequences, and make their Current sticky again.

@TheodorZoulias we do call MoveNext() on the next iteration, question is what happens at that time with the old value that Current() got us?.

@tinmanjk the old value becomes eligible for garbage collection, because no one holds a reference to it.

@TheodorZoulias so the first line of your answer "No, it won't become eligible for garbage collection." should be edited, don't you think?

@tinmanjk no, this line is fine. What I had to do was to answer directly the OP's question, which I hadn't done initially because I had misunderstood the question. I think that my answer is complete now (revision 4).

@TheodorZoulias, yeah great. I've modified my answer too with an experiment with WeakReference and reached the same conclusion from your last editions:
"So when exactly is the Current replaced by the next value of the sequence? It is replaced when the next MoveNextAsync operation completes asynchronously. In other words it is replaced when the ValueTask completes, not when the MoveNextAsync operation is launched. This can be proved experimentally. Let's observe for example the behavior of the sequence below:"


Will the item become free-able (by the GC) pretty much immediately
once Consumer has printed its first line and hits the second awaitable
iteration of the loop?

The answer is

NO, if there are more items to come
YES, if it's the last item

That's because the Current property has a backing field that is not reset until the end of the execution of the state machine.
The current implementation for .NET 6 with decompilation:
[CompilerGenerated] private sealed class <Producer>d__8:
IAsyncEnumerable<LargeObject>, IAsyncEnumerator<LargeObject>,
IAsyncDisposable, IValueTaskSource<bool>, IValueTaskSource,
IAsyncStateMachine 
{ 

private LargeObject<> 2__current;

LargeObject IAsyncEnumerator<LargeObject>.Current 
{
     [DebuggerHidden]
    get
     {
        return <> 2__current;
     } 
 }

}

MoveNext relevant parts:
try{
    ...
    <> 2__current = result;
num = (<> 1__state = -4);
goto IL_01b8;
end_IL_000e:;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{

    <> 1__state = -2;

    <> 2__current = null;

    <> t__builder.Complete();

    <> v__promiseOfValueOrEnd.SetException(exception);
return;
}

<> 1__state = -2;

<> 2__current = null;

<> t__builder.Complete();

<> v__promiseOfValueOrEnd.SetResult(false);
return;
IL_01b8:

<> v__promiseOfValueOrEnd.SetResult(true);

Old Answer: Empirically testing with WeakReference
We could find out by making use of WeakReference type which doesn't keep an object alive for GC but still holds a reference to it for diagnostic purposes.
The following is using most of the original example:
#LINQPad optimize+
async Task Main() {
    await Consumer();
}

public class LargeObject {
    public int _state;
    public LargeObject(int state) => _state = state;
}

Task<LargeObject> GetItem(int state) => Task.FromResult(new LargeObject(state));

const int ENUMERATOR_DELAY = 500;
public async IAsyncEnumerable<LargeObject> Producer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await Task.Delay(ENUMERATOR_DELAY);
        yield return await GetItem(i);
    }
}

public async Task Consumer() {
    var iterationCount = 0;

    await foreach (var item in Producer()) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Iteration: {iterationCount} Item State: {item._state}");

        WeakReference weakRef = new WeakReference(item);
        var weakRefHashCode = weakRef.GetHashCode();

        WaitCallback action = (waitTime) => {
            var weakRefHashCodeEntering = $">>>WeakRef {weakRefHashCode}: ";
            Thread.Sleep((int)waitTime);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();

            if (weakRef.IsAlive) {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>" + weakRefHashCodeEntering + "Item State: " + ((LargeObject)weakRef.Target)._state);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>" + weakRefHashCodeEntering + "The object has been garbage collected.");
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"WeakRef {weakRefHashCode}");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(action, ENUMERATOR_DELAY - 100);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(action, ENUMERATOR_DELAY + 100);

        Console.WriteLine("---End iteration---");
        iterationCount++;
    }
}

And the output on my PC:
Iteration: 0 Item State: 0
WeakRef 38458852
---End iteration---
>>>>>>WeakRef 38458852: Item State: 0
Iteration: 1 Item State: 1
WeakRef 49945755
---End iteration---
>>>>>>WeakRef 38458852: The object has been garbage collected.
>>>>>>WeakRef 49945755: Item State: 1
Iteration: 2 Item State: 2
WeakRef 28256950
---End iteration---
>>>>>>WeakRef 49945755: The object has been garbage collected.
>>>>>>WeakRef 28256950: The object has been garbage collected.
>>>>>>WeakRef 28256950: The object has been garbage collected.

I am using two callbacks - one runs BEFORE the next item is ready and one that runs AFTER the next item is ready.
So in the time after we return from the first iteration and before the second result is there, there is still a reference to the "Current" object.
Notice the two lines with identical hash-codes for the WeakRef.
---End iteration---
>>>>>>WeakRef 38458852: Item State: 0
Iteration: 1 Item State: 1
WeakRef 49945755
---End iteration---
>>>>>>WeakRef 38458852: The object has been garbage collected.

